# Crontab Error opening terminal: unknown

Tags: cron

Trying to execute command `echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > /var/www/graph.html` from crontab, but it returns *Error opening terminal: unknown.*

Command runs well from terminal. Should i somehow make cronjob run from terminal? System is running on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this has something to do with htop requiring a TERM environment variable to be present in order to run; I don't think cron has that when it picks up tasks by default. This post https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=94780 may be of help.

Comment: This article wasnt very useful solving the case. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Created a while loop with sleep option for the command, so it never stops. But still not the most elegant way.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a really old question, but maybe this will help someone still...

You need to export TERM environment variable before you execute htop. I did it by creating a script file and scheduling that:

```
#!/bin/bash
export TERM=xterm-256color
/usr/bin/echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > /data/diagnostics/htop-$(date +'%Y-%m-%dT%T').html
```